# UIPageViewController and UIPageControl transparent background color - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol, uibackgroundcolor

I'm making a tutorial when app launches for the first time and using `UIPageViewController` for that. Everything is working fine but the background color of `UIPageViewController` is not getting transparent. It's always black, as shown below:

[image]
[image]

Here's how I'm adding the `UIPageViewController` (in a tabbar controller)

.h file:

```
@interface CHMainTabViewController : UITabBarController <UIPageViewControllerDataSource>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPageViewController *pageViewController;
@end
```

.m file (in `viewDidLoad`):

```
// Create page view controller
self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;
self.pageViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
TutorialViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];

                NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];

                [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
[self presentViewController:_pageViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

in my AppDelegate.m, I've also set `UIPageControl`'s background color to clear:

```
UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[pageControl setOpaque:NO];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

I know that the issue is with the `UIPageViewController`'s background color. Is it not possible to set a Controller's background to be transparent?

Please help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay I've found the solution:

1. Set a background image on the `UIPageViewController`.

`UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
 view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
 UIImageView *imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"login_backgroung"]];
imageView1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
[view addSubview:imageView1];`

```
// Create page view controller
self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard 

instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;
self.pageViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];                  
[self.pageViewController.view insertSubview:view atIndex:0];
```

2. For your PageViewController `viewControllers` , choose a PNG Image with graphics or whatever you want, but make sure the background is transparent.
3. Set your `UIPageControl`'s background as transparent in `appDelegate.m`

   `UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor whisperWhite];
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor whisperDarkGray];
    pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`

Now run and your `UIPageViewController` will look like this, (notice the background static and only the text is moving, as we swipe from right to left):
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Set these to the page view controller before presenting it

```
pageViewController.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = YES;
pageViewController.definesPresentationContext = YES;
[pageViewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext];
```

Comment: This fixed my issue with no image for a background and I wanted the content behind the page controller to come through.