# How to set viewController bg transparent so that bg colour of the pageViewController remains standard background for all viewcontrollers?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

In the below image the viewController background is white and the pageViewController background colour is visible. How do I clear or make transparent the viewController background so that the violet is a standard background colour for all viewControllers.

[image: the image]

Comment: clear your pageviewcontroller background color

Comment: see this for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33680281/uipageviewcontroller-and-uipagecontrol-transparent-background-color-ios

Comment: @selva balasubramanian Then give the View controller bg as  the same bg colour of pageviewcontroller..

Comment: right now i am testing with colour....i am switch it to bgimage by adding subview in pagecontroller...

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I tried that one,...i am able to add subview yet the viewcontroller white background is visible..

Comment: @selvabalasubramanian - pardon this bgimage by adding subview

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i did in the same way the link u sent....but i am facing the same problem..

Comment: @selvabalasubramanian - is this possible to attach your projec

Comment: guys i got it....i used a collection view which is white in color...when i set its color to UIcolor.clear it works fine...thanks for your response :)...

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite init method and `self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;`, then set backgroudcolor clearColor.