# PageViewController transparent or no background

Tags: swift, swift3, uipageviewcontroller

I have problem with PageViewController dots indicators. Actually with background. I tried UIColor.clear but this didn't help. Background still white. I can change the color but I don't know how to remove it or make it transparent.

Can't find a way how to make it transparent.

Screenshot attached.

How to make background color transparent or remove it?

[image: Screenshot]

**ViewController.swift**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

   // Hide status bar.
override var prefersStatusBarHidden : Bool {
    return true
  }

var pageViewController: UIPageViewController!
let pages = ["DomesticPageViewController", "SafariPageViewController", "ForestPageViewController"]

// Page View Controller Datasource

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    if let index = pages.index(of: viewController.restorationIdentifier!) {
        if index > 0 {
            return viewControllerAtIndex(index - 1)
        }
    }

    return nil
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    if let index = pages.index(of: viewController.restorationIdentifier!) {
        if index < pages.count - 1 {
            return viewControllerAtIndex(index + 1)
        }
    }

    return nil
}


func viewControllerAtIndex(_ index: Int) -> UIViewController? {
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: pages[index])
    return vc

}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyPageViewController") {
        self.addChildViewController(vc)
        self.view.addSubview(vc.view)

        pageViewController = vc as! UIPageViewController
        pageViewController.dataSource = self
        pageViewController.delegate = self

        pageViewController.setViewControllers([viewControllerAtIndex(0)!], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        pageViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)


    }

}

    private func setupPageControl() {
        let appearance = UIPageControl.appearance()
        appearance.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
        appearance.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black
        appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear


}

    func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        setupPageControl()
        return self.pages.count
    }

    func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return 0
    }


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

**DomesticViewController.swift**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class DomesticPageViewController: UIViewController {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "domestic_bg1")
    backgroundImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
    self.view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIPageViewController and UIPageControl transparent background color - iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33680281/uipageviewcontroller-and-uipagecontrol-transparent-background-color-ios)

Comment: Have you tried setting it through StoryBoard.?

Comment: Are You using pageControl or PageViewController.?